# ‘Within 25 ft. of’ or ‘within 25 ft. from’?

Tags: prepositions

There is a sign at Harvard (shown below) that says:

> Thank you for not smoking within 25 feet from this building

That ‘from’ sounds odd to me. Is ‘within [distance] from [thing]’ used? If so, how—and does it differ from ‘within [distance] of [thing]’?

[image: Sign at Harvard]

Comment: Not even asking about the lack of a period.

Comment: Well, you know those Harvard guys were never very good at English.

Comment: Maybe the thanks are "from this building".

Comment: Maybe Harvard only hires its own graduates as sign painters.

Comment: Technically, if one draws a boundary 25 feet *from* the building, and one is *within* that boundary, one is "encouraged" to not smoke.  But I can think of a half-dozen better ways to word it.

Comment: Also technically, the *from* wording includes the interior of the building while the *of* wording (which is idiomatic) doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use golf as an illustrative example. Standard parlance is as follows:

*I hit my ball within 25 feet **of** the pin.* This means that my ball is no more than 25 feet from the pin. No one would say, *I hit my ball within 25 feet **from** the pin.* ***From*** the pin implies a definite distance, an equality, not an inequality.

*My ball is 25 feet **from** the pin.* This means that I've measured (figuratively speaking) the distance between my ball and the pin and found that distance to be 25 feet. No one would say *My ball is 25 feet **of** the pin.* Doesn't make sense.

Now let's replace *pin* by *building*:

*I hit my ball within 25 feet **of** the building.* This means that the shortest distance between my ball and any part of the building is less than 25 feet. No one would say, *I hit my ball within 25 feet **from** the building*. ***From*** the building implies a definite distance, an equality, not an inequality.

*My ball is 25 feet **from** the building*. This means that I've measured (figuratively speaking) the distance between my ball and the closet point of the building and found that distance to be 25 feet. No one would say *My ball is 25 feet **of** the building.* Doesn't make sense.

So, when the distance between A and B is X, one would always say *A is X feet away **from** B* (or vice versa), not *A is X feet away **of** B* (or vice versa).

Similarly, when the distance between A and B is less than X, one would always say *A is within X feet **of** B*, not *A is within X feet **from** B*.

If you think I'm belaboring the obvious, feel free to assume I went to Harvard ... and majored in English.

Comment: What did  Nietzsche  tietzsche?

Comment: This is most likely the best answer.

Comment: @Jiminion Nietzsche tietzsche, "Read slowly."

Answer (score 0):

Oh! the versatility of English!  One could actually use either of the structures.
Personally, I would more often use 'of'
eg: Thank you for not smoking 'inside of' 25 feet 'from' this building.

Answer (score -1):

I would tend to say of rather than from.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers.